# Using eloquent when filtering data without redundancy

Tags: ajax, laravel, filter, eloquent, redundancy

I'm trying to filter data via Eloquent in a method that only answers to AJAX requests and then returns the view along with the filtered data. However I have a question:

First, lets take a look at my code:

```
public function AJAX_get_reports(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax())
    {
        $message = $request->get('message');
        $severity = $request->get('severity');

        if(strlen($message) > 0 && strlen($severity) > 0 )
        {
            $data = ServerReport::where('severity', '=', $severity)->where('message', '=', $message)->get();
        } elseif (strlen($message) > 0) {
            $data = ServerReport::where('message', '=', $message)->get();
        } elseif (strlen($severity) > 0) {
            $data = ServerReport::where('severity', '=', $severity)->get();
        } else {
            $data = ServerReport::all();
        }
        return Response::json(View::make('dashboard.reports.index', compact('data'))->render());

    }
}
```

This was the only way I was able to do it, it works but I feel like it's not the best way to do this, especially if you have more fields to filter, the code would take enormous proportions with the verifications, is there a best way to do this?

For example, building the query while making verifications and then run it at the end?

```
if(strlen($message) > 0)
{
    // add WHERE to query
}
if(strlen($severity) > 0)
{
    // add WHERE to query
}

// Execute query and get the results
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, your code could be simplified like so:

```
public function AJAX_get_reports(Request $request) {
    if($request->ajax()) {
        $message = $request->get('message');
        $severity = $request->get('severity');
        $report = ServerReport::select('*'); //Initiate the variable for query container, change * to the columns that needs to be returned or just leave it

        if (strlen($message) > 0) {
            $report->where('message', '=', $message); //Add message filter
        }

        if (strlen($severity) > 0) {
            $report->where('severity', '=', $severity); //Add severity filter
        }

        //Add another filters if needed

        $data = $report->get(); //Get the data from either the filtered data or every single data without any filters

        return Response::json(View::make('dashboard.reports.index', compact('data'))->render());
    }
}
```

I have used this method for some projects in my company, and everything works just fine. Give it a shot.

Comment: Thank you sir, this is what I was looking for. Much more simplified.

Comment: Happy to help you. More simplified and more efficient of course. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that there is necessarily a best way to do this, considering what you produced in your original code looks perfectly valid to me, but there are certainly options. If you have WHERE clauses you use regularly, for example, you could use scopes to centralize building conditionals that aim to achieve a particular result, and stack them as necessary. This allows you the flexibility in the future to change one place in code and impact all the other places where the updated scope was being used, in the event your condition must be modified. But that may have more to do with larger issues of code maintainability than I think you might be looking for in this particular instance.

Personally, I've used your hypothetical method quite a bit. It works great for me when I have an API endpoint for a resource that is filterable, and the filters can be variable. Search for users by any combination of first name, last name, and/or email, for example.

Here's what that looks like for me:

```
public function getIndex(Request $request, Response $response)
{
    //Start with a copy of the model
    //I prefer to instantiate the class from the container,
    //instead of having it auto-injected using the method signature
    //just personal preference
    $users = app('App\User');

    //Filter by first name
    if ($request->has('first_name')) {
        $users->where('first_name', $request->input('first_name'));
    }

    //Filter by last name
    if ($request->has('last_name')) {
        $users->where('last_name', $request->input('last_name'));
    }

    //Filter by email
    if ($request->has('email')) {
        $users->where('email', $request->input('email'));
    }

    //If no conditions were set, get() *should* function like all()
    $data = $users->get();

    //Do what you need with the data from here on out
    //Typically I paginate the results for something like this
}
```

I find this to be a good convention for a few reasons. First, I find the code to be highly readable, as each block tends to self-document itself well (*if* the *request* *has* *email* ... ). Second, I can easily remove any block that needs to be removed the future quickly and easily without having to unwind anything.

One big caveat to this approach is that each filter acts independent from the others - choose 0 or more filters in any combination. It gets a little trickier if you find yourself in a situation where you can filter by combinations of groups. Even there though you can usually separate the combinations into their own blocks and achieve roughly the same thing.

So again, I think what you have from the first part of your question is perfectly valid, but would suggest the code from the second part of question as a cleaner and more maintainable option.